Handle return results by MassProp command in Python
I'm trying to handle return results by MassProp command in Python code:

acad.doc.SendCommand("MassProp")
res1 = acad.doc.GetVariable("AREA");
res2 = acad.doc.GetVariable("USERR2");
res3 = acad.doc.GetVariable("USERR3");
res4 = acad.doc.GetVariable("USERR4")
res5 = acad.doc.GetVariable("USERR5")

I'm trying to do it by reading USERR1-USERR5 env vars. But all they have 0.0 values.
But Autocad env returns on screen such result for some region:
---------------- REGIONS ----------------
Area: 373.3232
Perimeter: 79.9499
Bounding box: X: 9.9847 -- 35.0884
Y: 5.0765 -- 19.9477
Centroid: X: 22.5366
Y: 12.5121
Moments of inertia: X: 65324.9322
Y: 209215.5765
Product of inertia: XY: -105269.7286
Radii of gyration: X: 13.2281
Y: 23.6731
Principal moments and X-Y directions about centroid:
I: 6880.1556 along [1.0000 0.0000]
J: 19605.5483 along [0.0000 1.0000]
Can you help please how to get these parameters in Python code?
this code
import pyautocad 
acad = pyautocad.Autocad()

reslt = acad.get_selection(text='select objects') 
solid = acad.IAcad3DSolid(reslt[0])

returns
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Work\PyACAD\PyACAD\PyACAD.py", line 36, in solid = acad.model.IAcad3DSolid(reslt[0]) File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\lazybind.py", line 145, in getattr descr = self.__bind(name, DISPATCH_METHOD | DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET) File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\lazybind.py", line 109, in __bind descr = self._tcomp.Bind(name, invkind)[1] File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\site-packages\comtypes\typeinfo.py", line 456, in Bind raise NameError("Name %s not found" % name) NameError: Name IAcad3DSolid not found


You have the document, you can query the solid directly
        reslt = acad.doc.Utility.GetEntity("\nSelect a solid")
        solid = acad.IAcad3DSolid(reslt[0])
        mp = {}
        mp['BoundingBox'] = solid.GetBoundingBox()
        mp['Centroid'] = solid.Centroid
        mp['MomentOfInertia'] = solid.MomentOfInertia
        mp['ProductOfInertia'] = solid.ProductOfInertia
        


Thank you,
but when I do
python.exe -m pip install pyrx_impx
I'm getting
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable                                                               ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyrx_impx (from versions: none)                                              ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyrx_impx

sorry the command is from https://github.com/CEXT-Dan/PyRx, you can start your code from axDoc, since you have acad.doc, it should be the same

this code:
import pyautocad
acad = pyautocad.Autocad()
reslt = acad.get_selection(text='select objects')
solid = acad.IAcad3DSolid(reslt[0])

Sorry about that, here is the object model
https://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2024/ENU/?guid=GUID-FC6FC3E3-ED3E-4E4D-9766-8E4D037241A5
I’m not sure how PyAutocad does casting. But once you get the solid, you can get it’s properties
